# PyXB says AttributeError: 'module' object

Tags: python, xml, binding, wsdl

I have problems creating a python binding for a WSDL file using PyXB. I do:

- pip install pyxb (currently version 1.1.5)
- pyxbwsdl http://dic.googlecode.com/files/GoogleSearch.wsdl

I get "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateFromDOM'" and no code is generated. For another WSDL document I get the same error.

Can someone give me a clue?
Thanks!

Full stack trace:

```
ERROR: Unable to convert DOM node {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema to Python instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boehlke/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxb/binding/basis.py", line 2047, in append
    value = mr.module().CreateFromDOM(node)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateFromDOM'
```

Comment: Can you include the *full* traceback?

Comment: thx, I added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that "AttributeError: 'module' object..." is an expected error. I found this comment in the source code, where the error occurs :-)

> ```
>                                 # The module holding XMLSchema bindings
>                                 # does not have a CreateFromDOM method,
>                                 # and shouldn't since we need to convert
>                                 # schema instances to DOM more carefully.
>                                 # Other namespaces won't have a module if
>                                 # the bindings were not imported; this is
>                                 # probably worth a warning.
> ```